# Riemann sum of a periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, periodic-functions

While reading a paper in mathematical physics (I am a physicist) I stumbled upon this statement :

*Note first that in the case of variables $q_j$,  $1 \leq j\leq N$ which are homogeneously distributed inside an interval of length $\pi$ (i.e. $q_{j+1}-q_j=\frac{\pi}{N}$) such that f(q) is $\pi$-periodic, it is easy to prove the following proposition :* 
$\frac{1}{M}\sum\limits_{j=1}^Nf(q_j)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(q)dq + O(M^{-\infty})$ 
(they didn't mention that f(q) is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ because it is clear in the rest of the paper that it is the case)

I tried to get the result in a simpler context with :
$f(x)$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ with period $1$ trying to get : 
$\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{j=1} ^n f(\frac{j}{n})= \int\limits_0^1f(x)dx+ O(n^{-\infty})$

**Can anyone somehow show me how to prove this ? (or help me find a book/paper where it is explained in more details)**

*here is my attempt at getting the result*

I start from $\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx$ and rewrite it as the following sum (which I believe is a Riemann sum): 
$\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx = \sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}f(\frac{j}{n}+x)dx$

Then I taylor expand the RHS of the equation to get the following:

$\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx = \sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(f(\frac{j}{n})+x f'(\frac{j}{n}) + \frac{x^2}{2!}f''(\frac{j}{n})+ \frac{x^3}{3!}f'''(\frac{j}{n})+ ...\right)dx$.

Which is the same as :
$\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx = \sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}f(\frac{j}{n})dx+\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}x f'(\frac{j}{n})dx +\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} \frac{x^2}{2!}f''(\frac{j}{n})dx+\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} \frac{x^3}{3!}f'''(\frac{j}{n})dx+ ...$

Now evaluating the integral at each term I get :

$\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx = \sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{j}{n})\frac{1}{n}+\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2n^2} f'(\frac{j}{n}) +\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2!} \frac{1}{3n^3}f''(\frac{j}{n})+\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{3!} \frac{1}{4n^4}f'''(\frac{j}{n})+ ...$

And finally, taking the first term on the RHS to the LHS I get :

$\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{j}{n})=\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx - \left(\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2n^2} f'(\frac{j}{n}) +\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2!} \frac{1}{3n^3}f''(\frac{j}{n})+\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{3!} \frac{1}{4n^4}f'''(\frac{j}{n})+ ...\right)$ [1]

Which is the furthest I can get till now.

My idea to move forward is the following :

I take the first term from the parenthesis of equation [1]:  $\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2n^2} f'(\frac{j}{n})$ and since the derivative of a periodic function is also periodic I can apply [1] to this term and thus get :

$\frac{1}{2n} \frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1} f'(\frac{j}{n}) =\frac{1}{2n} \left(\int\limits_0^1f'(x)dx - \left(\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2n^2} f''(\frac{j}{n}) +\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2!} \frac{1}{3n^3}f'''(\frac{j}{n})+...\right)\right)$

We know that $\int\limits_0^1f'(x)dx =f(1)-f(0)=0$ (period $1$ of $f(x)$) so we are left with the other terms which now are of one lower order in n ($n^{-2}\rightarrow n^{-3}$).

Applying this recursively to all the terms in [1] should always get me to one lower order in n and thus the correction should be of $O(n^{-\infty})$ which leads to the final result of :

$\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{j=1} ^n f(\frac{j}{n})= \int\limits_0^1f(x)dx+ O(n^{-\infty})$ such that when $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have $\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{j=1} ^n f(\frac{j}{n})= \int\limits_0^1f(x)dx$

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is rediscover the Euler-Maclaurin formula. It is easy to see that a $C^\infty$ periodic function has equal values for all derivatives at the endpoints of the integration interval, and hence all terms in the asymptotic series vanish.

Comment: Thanks for the remark ! So what I am doing is correct ? 
Indeed, i know that all the integrals of the derivatives of f from one end point to the other will vanish. I am just not sure if this is the right way to get to this proof

Comment: It seems correct, just cumbersome to formalize. I would have done something [along these lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out ! So basically Euler-Maclaurin + periodicity would lead to my result ?